# Using Large function to Return Names of Equal Values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am currently using the Large function to try and return the top three values in aa array. So if my array looked like:

```
{A:1,B:1,C:0}
```

I would want it to return A then B then C when changing the k value in the large function, but at the moment it is producing A then A again and then C. How would I go about fixing this issue?
My function at the moment to return the value names is:

```
=INDEX(A1:B28,MATCH(LARGE(B1:B28,k),B1:B28,0),1)
```

Any help or feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So this isn't ideal, but I've seen some people add a really small random number ex. =rand()/999999 to each cell and then use the large function. Then they round the number back to the correct interval.

Comment: @Hooded One Don't recommend RAND() as a tie breaker because it might not break the tie. Way to go is to use a fraction of ROW() in the way you describe.

Comment: Show some sample data for clear understanding.

Comment: I ended up adding a unique small constant to each value in my table. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Search for top 5 or top 10 with duplicates for other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using `SORT` and `INDEX`functions. Check the following code:

```
=INDEX(SORT(A1:B28,2,-1),k,1)
```

I believe `SORT` is only available for Office 365. [Check this out](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sort-function-22f63bd0-ccc8-492f-953d-c20e8e44b86c) for more information in the function.